# Recursively generate Compositions from an ordered list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, recursion, combinatorics

Given an ordered list of 'n' elements, I want to slice the list to generate every distinct permutation of sublists once only, whilst maintaining the order of the original list - i.e. generate every *Composition* of my input list. (This is not the same as calculating every possible Combination of possible sublists from my input list).

For example, given input list `[A,B,C,D]`, my output would be the following 8 nested lists:

```
[[A,B,C,D]], [[A,B,C],[D]], [[A,B],[C,D]], [[A,B],[C],[D]], [[A],[B,C],[D]], [[A],[B],[C,D]], [A,[B,C,D]], [[A],[B],[C],[D]].
```

Drawing a tree of possible permutations suggests that this problem would lend itself to a recursive algorithm, but I'm not sure how to implement this in Python for maximum speed and efficiency, and would be very grateful for your advice and guidance.

Comment: You've missed [[A], [BCD]]. Isn't the number of possible results `2^(n - 1)` for lists of `n` elements? You can represent the separations as binary number with `n - 1` bits; each bit represents a gap.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)

Comment: Thanks for spotting this so quickly. Original question edited appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def composition(seq):
    seq = tuple(seq)
    for i in range(2**(len(seq)-1)):
        result = [[seq[0]]]
        for j in range(len(seq)-1):
            if i & (1<<j):
                result.append([seq[j+1]])
            else:
                result[-1].append(seq[j+1])
        yield result

if __name__=="__main__":
    from pprint import pprint
    pprint(list(composition('ABCD')))
```

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)